# Как создать объект и добавить его в существующей ArrayList

Tags: java, массивы, объекты, arraylist, scanner

Задача спросить у пользователя какие данные нужно ввести в новый объект и добавить этот объект в существующей ArrayList.

Есть ArrayList с объектами

```
        Product p1 = new Product("1", "Windows 10 key", "534", "20");
        Product p2 = new Product("2", "AMD RX 480 4G", "23", "240");
        Product p3 = new Product("3", "Apple iPhone X 128GB", "4", "500");
        Product p4 = new Product("4", "nVidia GTX 2060", "11", "600");
        Product p5 = new Product("5", "SteelSeries APEX", "5", "150");
        Product p6 = new Product("6", "Coffee 1 KG", "3", "25");

        ArrayList<Product> product = new ArrayList<Product>();

        product.add(p1);
        product.add(p2);
        product.add(p3);
        product.add(p4);
        product.add(p5);
        product.add(p6);
```

Нужно сделать новый объект с введёнными пользователем данные

```
System.out.println("If you would like too add a new product, please press \"Y\" button");
            String addAction = input.nextLine();
            if (addAction.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

                System.out.print("input number of the product: ");
                String productNumber = input.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Input name of the product: ");
                String productName = input.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Input in stock units: ");
                String productInStock = input.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Input price of the product: ");
                String productPrice = input.nextLine();

                Product p[counter] = new Product();

                p.setNumber(productNumber);
                p.setName(productName);
                p.setInStock(productInStock);
                p.setPrice(productPrice);
```

Не работает. Не понимаю логику, что нужно сделать, что бы добавить новый объект, например p7, p8 и т.д., и при этом, что бы данные были заполнены пользователем.

То есть вручную мы можем написать

```
Product p7 = new Product("1", "Windows 10 key", "534", "20");
```

Но как сделать, что бы мы спросили данные у пользователя и добавлять новые объекты в существующей ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, в цикле после ввода переменных

```
Product newProduct = new Product(productNumber, productName, productInStock, productPrice);
product.add(newProduct);
```

либо

```
            Product p = new Product();

            p.setNumber(productNumber);
            p.setName(productName);
            p.setInStock(productInStock);
            p.setPrice(productPrice);
            product.add(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

В цикле нет смысла каждый раз этому объекту присваивать уникальное имя. На каждой итеррации будет создаваться объект типа Product и добавляться в список

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]